# How to build system apps in Android Studio?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, system

By system apps, I'm referring to things like settings.apk, framework-res.apk etc.

As of now, most of my issues are coming from "duplicate" strings such as

```
<string name="photoPickerNotFoundText" product="tablet" msgid="6247290728908599701">"У пристрої немає доступних зображень."</string>
<string name="photoPickerNotFoundText" product="default" msgid="431331662154342581">"У телефоні немає доступних зображень."</string>
```

There are two strings with the same name, but for a different product, which causes an error when building gradle. Is there any way to fix that?

I remember reading somewhere about a similar question for building settings.apk, but I can't seem to find it anymore. As a final note, I was just wondering if it was possible to build these apps on a pc, rather than on a linux system with linaro.

Thanks!

Comment: Change the `Name` there is no way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the PackageName.NO other way.